# Cambiar texto botón submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero que al hacer click en el botón de un formulario de registro este cambie el texto, pero no consigo que esto suceda. Imagino es un error tonto, pero llevo sin verlo casi dos días y quizás otros ojos...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#LogInForm').bind('submit', function() {

    $.ajax({
      type: $(this).attr('method'),
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      beforeSend: function() {
        $('#btn').text("TEXTO NUEVO");
      },
      success: function(response) {
        if (response.estado == "true") {
          $("body").overhang({
            type: "success",
            message: "Usuario encontrado, estás siendo redirigido",
            callback: function() {
              window.location.href = "admin.php"
            }
          });
        } else {
          $("body").overhang({
            type: "error",
            message: "Usuario incorrecto"
          });
        }
      },
      error: function() {
        $("body").overhang({
          type: "error",
          message: "Usuario incorrecto"
        });


      }
    });
    return false;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="logIn">
  <form id="LogInForm" action="PHP/LogIn/validarLoginRegistro.php" method="post">
    <h2 class="texto">Log In</h2>
    <input type="text" name="usuario" class="texto" placeholder="Nombre" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" name="clave" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
    <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Entrar">
    <p>Cuidado porque es Case Sensitive</p>
  </form>

</div>
```

en concreto la linea problemática es (creo):

```
$('#btn').text("TEXTO NUEVO");
```

Se que no es antes porque puse un alert en el beforeSend y si que se me muestra.

Salud!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En un `input` de tipo `submit` el texto mostrado en el botón se corresponde con el valor del `input` (la propiedad `value`). Para cambiarlo con jQuery deberías utilizar el método `val`, no el `text`:

```
$('#btn').val("TEXTO NUEVO");
```